# GCS Error during retriving signed URLs from GCP (SignatureDoesNotMatch)

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, spring-cloud-gcp

I use Java and Spring framework. I store encrypted files (with customer-supplied encryption keys) in GCP. When I try to return signed url for given blob from GCP, I get following error: *SignatureDoesNotMatch*, with message: *The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.*.
I modified code from this article [GCS Customer supplied keys](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/using-customer-supplied-keys#client-libraries)

That's how I upload files into the cloud:

```
private void saveFile(BlobInfo blobInfo, String bucketName, InputStream inputStream, Storage.PredefinedAcl acl) {           
 try {               
  storage.create(blobInfo, inputStream.readAllBytes(),                         Storage.BlobTargetOption.predefinedAcl(acl),   Storage.BlobTargetOption.encryptionKey(ENCRYPTION_KEY));          
 } catch (IOException e) { 
  //          
 }      
}
```

The problem occurs only when I try to invoke method signUrl(). Files are encrypted correctly. For testing purposes I wrote following code:

```
Blob blob = storage.get(BlobId.of(bucketName, name));  
File file = new File("<path to folder>/test.txt");  
blob.downloadTo(file.toPath(), Blob.BlobSourceOption.decryptionKey(ENCRYPTION_KEY));
```

In given example, the blob is decrypted correctly and stored in given file. However, I want to return URL to the end user instead.

Here's my method for aforementioned URL retrieval:

```
private String getFileUrl(String bucketName, String name) {
try {

            Blob blob = storage.get(BlobId.of(bucketName, name));
            
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("x-goog-encryption-algorithm", blob.getCustomerEncryption().getEncryptionAlgorithm());
            headers.put("x-goog-encryption-key", ENCRYPTION_KEY);
            headers.put("x-goog-encryption-key-sha256", blob.getCustomerEncryption().getKeySha256());
    
            return blob.signUrl(
                    10,
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES,
                    Storage.SignUrlOption.signWith(credentials),
                    Storage.SignUrlOption.withExtHeaders(headers)
            ).toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       //
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, I am always receiving Error: *SignatureDoesNotMatch*. I tried also add option   `Storage.BlobGetOption.decryptionKey(ENCRYPTION_KEY)` inside `storage.get()` method, but also no success.

Comment: I've managed to solve that issue by switching from customer-supplied keys to customer-managed keys.